# How to Check helper file is loaded?

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter

I want to check helper file is loaded or not. I can check libraries file using

```
if( $this->load->is_loaded('session') ) {
    // $this->load->library('session');
    echo "loaded";
} else {
    echo "not loaded";
}
```

But if I want to check

```
if( $this->load->is_loaded('url') ) {
    echo "loaded";
} else {
    echo "not loaded";
}
```

it is not giving a positive answer.

Please let me know how to check helper file.

Answer (score 1):

Helper files only define global functions. If the "url" helper file is loaded, then `site_url` function will be defined, so you can make a check like:

```
if (function_exists('site_url') === false) {
    echo "helper not loaded"
}
```

Comment: if site_url is exist and we want to unset this method how we can do that?please help me.

Comment: Unfortunately you can not. Why do you even want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can check with php function function_exists()

Take a look [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php)

example:

```
if (function_exists('function_name')) 
{
    echo "is loaded";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create new file MY_Loader to application/core directory with following content

```
    class MY_Loader extends CI_Loader {
        public function is_helper_loaded($helper)
        {
            $helper = $this->_ci_prep_filename($helper, '_helper');

            if (isset($this->_ci_helpers[$helper]))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
}
```

then check $this->load->is_helper_loaded('url')